# How to add or remove list of values in Array based on checkbox selection in AngularJS and dynamic filteration?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

```
$scope.selectObjectType = function () {
    $scope.selected = []; // clear previous state
     $scope.model.allItemsSelected = true; // all are selected unless...
     // If any object type is not checked, then uncheck the "allItemsSelected" checkbox
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.objectTypes.length; i++) {
        if (!$scope.model.objectTypes[i].isChecked) { 
             //$scope.selected.splice($scope.model.objectTypes[i].value);
            $scope.model.allItemsSelected = false;
            return; 
        } else {
            if ($scope.selected.indexOf($scope.model.objectTypes[i].value) == -1) {
                $scope.selected.push($scope.model.objectTypes[i].value);
            }
        }
    }
};

 // Fired when the checkbox "Show All" is checked
$scope.selectAll = function () {
    // Loop through all the object types and set their isChecked property
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.objectTypes.length; i++) {
        $scope.model.objectTypes[i].isChecked = $scope.model.allItemsSelected;
    }
};
```

Whenever i am clicking first "Show Activated" and "Show Inactivated" in that list it's adding to the array(selected).
  But if i am clicking " Show InActivated " as first. It's not adding to the array.

Same process for removing.

Please any one help to acheive this requirement.

Comment: There's a reason you couldn't add the link and you added it as code. Please add the code from the plunkr here too.

Comment: Solution : http://plnkr.co/edit/WyzAW6DK183gSz5tVrEs?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is you're code in a working version + comments where I changed things. This is the link to the modified [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WyzAW6DK183gSz5tVrEs?p=preview).

```
 $scope.selectObjectType = function () {
      $scope.selected = []; // clear previous state
      $scope.model.allItemsSelected = true; // all are selected unless...
     // If any object type is not checked, then uncheck the "allItemsSelected" checkbox
     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.objectTypes.length; i++) {
         if (!$scope.model.objectTypes[i].isChecked) { 
             //$scope.selected.splice($scope.model.objectTypes[i].value);
             $scope.model.allItemsSelected = false;
             // return; // if you return here all other select/unselect will be skipped
         } 
         else {
             if($scope.selected.indexOf($scope.model.objectTypes[i].value) == -1) {
                 $scope.selected.push($scope.model.objectTypes[i].value);
                }
         }

     }
 };

 // Fired when the checkbox "Show All" is checked
 $scope.selectAll = function () {
     // Loop through all the object types and set their isChecked property
     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.objectTypes.length; i++) {
         $scope.model.objectTypes[i].isChecked = $scope.model.allItemsSelected;
     }

     $scope.selectObjectType(); // add everything to array after select all - can be optimized
};
```

Comment: Now i got selected values in scope after that i have an another requirement based on the selected scope values ....please check this plunker. I that i explained my requirement clearly. http://plnkr.co/edit/PHyT7fH58YrFXgtXn2m2?p=preview